# Issue with python list for complex types

Tags: python, list, radix-tree, capnproto

Below is a code snippet in Python that stores the IP prefixes in a radix tree and then associates IP and ASNs in a dictionary, if the IP belongs to a prefix.

I would like to find out all different ASNs for a particular prefix. More details are provided below:

```
#rtree is a radix tree which has prefixes stored.
rtree = radix.Radix()    
with open(path-to-prefix-file,'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        rnode = rtree.add(line)  # Eg, Prefixes like "192.168.2.0/24"
        rnode.data["count"]= 0
...        
# The code has several lines here for processing a capnproto - skipping them.

rnode.data[IP]=asn_complete  # I read a Capnproto buffer and store IP and asn_complete

...

for rnode in rtree:
    seen_list = []  # defining a list to store different val, i.e.,asn_complete values
    if rnode.data["count"] > 1:
            """  Iterate through the rnode.data dictionary """
            for ip,val in rnode.data.iteritems():
                    if val not in seen_list:  # Condition is always satisfied!!
                            seen_list.append(val)
```

For eg: `val` has the following value from the protobuf in several iterations:

```
[<capnp list reader [15169]>, <capnp list reader [1239]>, <capnp list reader [4837]>]
```

When I print out the `seen_list`:

```
[[<capnp list reader [15169]>, <capnp list reader [1239]>, <capnp list reader [4837]>], [<capnp list reader [15169]>, <capnp list reader [1239]>, <capnp list reader [4837]>], [<capnp list reader [15169]>, <capnp list reader [1239]>, <capnp list reader [4837]>],....]
```

Clearly `val` is in `seen_list`; but, `if val not in seen_list:` is always true and `val` gets appended to `seen_list` so many times. I don't understand why the condition always returns true. Is it because of the type of object stored in `seen_list`?

Comment: Maybe every `val` is unique.

Comment: @luoluo, from the output of  `seen_list`, you can say `val` does hold the same value during many iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, Cap'n Proto readers do not support any sort of "equality" comparison. Partly this is because it's unclear what equality should mean: should it be by identity (two readers are equal if they point at exactly the same object) or should it be by value (they are equal if they point at objects with equivalent content)?

In any case, `in` requires an implementation of `__eq__` to test for equality, and in the case of Cap'n Proto there is no such implementation. Probably, what ends up happening is that Python is comparing the wrapper objects by identity -- and as new wrapper objects keep being created, these comparisons are always false.

In order to get what you want, you'll probably need to convert the Cap'n Proto objects fully into plain Python objects which are properly comparable.